# powershell sort & subsort multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm new at PowerShell. I'm working on how to do a sort & sub-sort of a multidimensional array. I have an array of addresses:

```
$Addresses += ,@($FirstName, $LastName, $Street, $City, $State, $ZIP);
```

I need to use the array in two ways. First sorted by last name then first name. Then later I need it sorted by state then city then last name.

I've figured out a one-level sort by last name:

```
$Addresses = $Addresses | sort-object @{Expression={$_[1]}; Ascending=$TRUE}
```

But I can't figure out how to sub-sort the resulting array by first name.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

UPDATE: Ok, I found the solution. I was so close. To sort by last name then first, use the expression:

```
$Addresses = $Addresses | sort-object @{Expression={$_[1],$_[0]}; Ascending=$TRUE}
```

Simple once I wrapped my brain about Sort-Object.

Comment: I would suggest using an array of custom objects rather than a multi dimensional array. Then you could do something like `$things | Sort-Object LastName,FirstName`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. As I've been using PowerShell for five days, I've a lot to learn.